# How can I ignore test projects in the build?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I have some integration tests that I don't want to be run by the .NET Core Test command in Azure DevOps. How can I filter them out?

I tried setting a specific project to test with the `Parameters.TestProjects` variable but it had no effect.

Comment: How do you define the tests to skip? Is it an entire test project, or just tests in a project?
Also it might help to mention the test framework - for example, xunit has conditional skip IIRC

Comment: Whole project. I’m using xunit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got your question correctly then the answer is:

Add "!" mark before the test assembly, like this:

```
**\*integrationtests.dll
!**\*TestAdapter.dll
!**\obj\**
```

So the integrationtests.dll will be included and the other 2 lines are excluded.

[image]

Comment: Cool. Is that a custom command? Doesn’t that drop the test specific options from the build step?

Comment: @IanWarburton I guessed it's the command you use. This is the only command I found by".NET Core" search query. I didn't get your second question so I cannot answer.

Comment: Oh, it's readonly for the default .NET Core build. If I manually add the step, it's not readonly.

Comment: It should be `.csproj` instead of `.dll`.